# MOSFET delay while switching

Tags: power-supply, mosfet, mosfet-driver, ups, powermosfet

[image]

I was making a UPS for my router. My battery voltage is 8 V and V1 is the output from the power adapter, which is also 8 V. When the power goes off, the MOSFET should switch to the battery output, otherwise it should run on the adapter's output.

But when the MOSFET switches from the adapter to the battery, my router reboots. I am not sure what could be causing this.
Here is the full circuit.
Please help.

[image: Full circuit]

Comment: The output voltage from the adapter probably doesn't drop from 8V to 0V instantly. Try adding a large enough electrolytic capacitor after D1.

Comment: Do you know how much current your router sucks from the 12V when operating?

Comment: the current consumption is 2A at 12v

Comment: What's "bug boost"?

Comment: You need diodes rated at least 2A continuous. Schottky would be best.

Answer (score 3):

You do not actually need transistor for the backup battery. Simply connect it through a diode:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2f0ATzr.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

Comment: I am using a MOSFET because, if there is no switching then it may affect the battery health. constant charging and discharging may degrade the battery. Hence, I am using a switching circuit with MOSFET

Comment: The diodes also switch the battery. But automatically and without problems. :P The battery is not charging in this schematic.

Answer (score 2):

I assume you have a separate boost circuit (not "bug" boost) that provides 12V for the router. Please provide more details of how they are connected. Also, your [IRF9530 MOSFET](https://www.vishay.com/docs/91076/91076.pdf) does not really turn on until gate voltage exceeds about 4.5V, at which point the output to the boost circuit will be only about 4V or less, and the modem will reset. You might do better to just replace the MOSFET with another diode, perhaps a Schottky to minimize voltage drop.

Answer (score 0):

I simulated this circuit. As KristoferA suggested put a cap of value 0.1 uF, 50 V at the output.I am not able to see any delay in switching.
It will be well and good if you can provide the complete circuit diagram.

[image]

[image]

Comment: Try your simulation with a pulse fall time of several hundred milliseconds to better simulate loss of power from a DC adapter with capacitor output. The voltage will likely drop to 4V or less before the MOSFET switches to battery power.

Comment: You should also simulate a load on V_OUT instead of floating it.  Unfortunately, the question doesn't provide that detail so I would start at something like a 500mA current sink with `load` flag set.  Capacitor size is going to depend on the load.

Comment: @PStechPaul,Can I keep rise time as it is.I am planning to use a fall time of 5ms.May I know your thoughts.

Comment: Not knowing the details of the discharge rate of the DC supply when power is removed, I'd try 500 mSec. There will also be a rise time associated with start-up of the supply, which may be 100ms or so. And you should replace the 1N914 with a diode (preferably Schottky) that can handle the 2A or so as the OP has revealed. Use a 6 ohm resistor for load. Then you can try a larger capacitor, probably 50,000 uF or so.

Answer (score 0):

How about connecting a P-channel MOSFET backwards so the body diode conducts while the transistor isn't turned on, yet. *Half a battery switch* style.
Wait - maybe use a battery switch?

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fbD7Ea.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>